# Can I "git pull" and ignore specific commits?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have a `dev branch` for staging and `master branch` for production. A lot of work has been done on staging and now I need to move things over to production. There is a feature I don't want to release yet on production but it has already been included in a pull request to master and merged.

I'd like to either of these:

1. make a new branch and use staging to remove the commit and set that branch to production till master branch is ready
2. go ahead and `git pull` everything to prod even the stuff I don't want yet, then tell my local repo to "remove" a few commits that have that feature.

I tried a `git revert <commit #>` but that caused some stability issues on staging that I'm still working out.

Comment: Do you mean that the feature has already been merged to `dev`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, you can, but this is similar to creating a new branch.

Just use `git fetch` to get the objects, then you can use `git log origin/master` to see the commits, and use both `git merge <sha>` and `git cherry-pick <sha>` to take only the commits you want. Be aware that once you start doing this, your history will diverge from `origin/master`, so this is essentially branching.

---

To make the merging phase clearer:

Assume you have on your local master branch:

```
A - B - C
```

On the remote master branch:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I
```

Now, if you want `D`, `E`, `F` and `H`, run:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b master-production # better work on a new branch
git merge F                       # grab everything until F
git cherry-pick H                 # grab H
```

The smaller and more atomic the commits are, the easier it should be.
This will eventually leave you with:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - H'
```

Where `H'` is a different commit from `H` (different sha-1), but with similar content.

Of course, the letters here stand for the respective sha-1 sums. you can identify them with `git log origin/master`, as previously noted.

---

You should note a couple of things:

- Doing a `git pull` really only does `git fetch origin; git merge origin/master` (assuming the remote is called `origin`, and your branch is `master`).
- In the above example, H' is a different commit (if only because it has different parents, so its sha-1 sum will be different. Once you start using cherry-pick, you are developing an "alternative timeline". That is, you are branching.
- From the point above, you can note that if you are using only `git merge` (for example, you are not interested in `H`), the history won't be altered, an you will be able to directly merge back `G`, `H`, `I` later without conflicts (just fast-forwarding your local branch).

Comment: So could I create a branch off master called, `tempMaster`, do what your suggesting, then (when everything lines back up), switch back to master?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the best way. Otherwise, you would have to do a forced pull or delete your local `master` branch. In either case, I hope for you that the feature will be ready soon.

Comment: Yeah, this is rare, waiting for functionality approval. I'll research on how to use `git merge` and `git cherry-pick` together to get my desired result.

Comment: I clarified a bit the whole merging part.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I “git pull” and ignore specific commits?

No.

> There is a feature I don't want to release yet on production but it has already been included in a pull request to master and merged.

This is generally why Git workflow guidance suggests not merging things to `master` until they are ready to be released.

Since that ship has sailed, I would consider these options:

1. Implement a [feature toggle](http://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) to allow the in-progress feature to be left in `master`, but disabled in production until it's ready.
2. Create a new branch from before the in-progress feature was merged as a starting point for building up a new release branch. Assuming you also wish to release features that have been merged since then, you can either `merge` their feature branches into your new branch, or cherry-pick in specific commits.
3. Create a new branch from `master` and use `revert` to unwind the commits that are part of the in-progress feature.

As you've already discovered, options 2 and 3 are going to be rather tedious and error-prone unless you've done a particularly good job of keeping features isolated from each other. Rather than prepare a separate version of the app with the in-progress feature removed, I would urge you toward option 1.

Comment: sorry, when I said "Can I “git pull” and ignore specific commits?" I was thinking about doing the full `git pull` then possible removing just the couple commits I don't want. Which I guess is what revert does.